# Density plot using NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I want solve a differential equation for varying parameter and then I wish to create a list which contains the parameter and corresponding value of differential equation. So that I can make a List Density plot.

differential equation is

```
f = y'[x] == a*Cos[x] + b*Sin[x];
Table[{a,b,NDSolve[{f,y[0]==1},y,{x,1,10}]},{a,1,5},{b,1,5}]
```

I want to have a list with parameter and its corresponding differential equation solution, like {{a,b,value},{a',b',value},{}}. So I can use ListDensity Plot .
Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include Mathematica code for what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have added a simple example which I am trying solve

Comment: What is the meaning of " So I can use ListDensity Plot"?

Comment: At the end I want to create a list. Basically I need to make a density plot of the diff equation for varying parameters

Comment: DensityPlot of `a,b` and `???` or `y[a,b][x]`?

Comment: Density Plot of the y[a,b][x]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Useing `ParametricNDSolveValue`.

```
Clear[sol];
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[x] == a*Cos[x] + b*Sin[x], 
    y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 1, 10}, {a, b}];
Block[{x = 5}, DensityPlot[sol[a, b]@x, {a, 1, 5}, {b, 1, 5}]]
```

[image]

```
DensityPlot3D[sol[a, b]@x, {a, 1, 5}, {b, 1, 5},{x, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It worked. What happens if there are more than one differential equations? Then how do you plot a specific differential equation?

Comment: @physicsgeek  You can ask a new equations and post a new code about it. Thanks your accption.

Comment: I have posted a different question. I t would be nice to have some help @cvgmt

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276143/density-plot-and-differential-equation

Answer (score 0):

Try `NDSolveValue` :

```
Table[{a,b,NDSolveValue[{f,y[0]==1},y,{x,1,10}]},{a,1,5},{b,1,5}]
```

Comment: I tried but it gives me a list which I cannot use to create a density plot using the command list density plot